# How do you predict the number of iterations it takes to perform a binary search?

Tags: python-3.x

How do you predict the number of iterations it takes to find a number that the user would input into the binary search?

```
def find(list, x):
    numIter=0
    a = 0 
    b = len(list) - 1
    while a < b:
        numIter+=1
        c = (a + b) // 2
        if list[c] <x: 
            a = c + 1
        else:  
            b = c
    return numIter
    if list[b] == x
        return b + 1
    else:
        return -1


print(find([1,2,4,5,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17], 10))
```

Comment: The same way you'd display any other number?  No really!  What are you really asking?  Are you asking how to return `numIter` from your `find()` function?  Are you asking how to _predict_ the number of iterations that will be needed?

Comment: predict the number of iterations that will be needed and show only number of iterations

Comment: I don't think you can actually take an input and _predict_ how many iterations it would take for a binary search without actually performing the binary search... this sounds a bit like [the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: @AetherUnbound, You can put an upper bound on it easily enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to put an upper bound on the number of iterations.  Each iteration divides the search space in half.  So, in the worst case the search will require log_base_2(*n*) iterations, where *n* is the size of the array.

It's not easy to get an exact answer without actually doing the search.  You might get lucky and find what you're looking for on the first try, or on the second try, or the third...   When you find it depends on the data, and it's kind of hard to know anything about the data without actually looking at it (i.e., by actually doing the search.)